# Split String in C#

Tags: c#

I thought this will be trivial but I can't get this to work.

Assume a line in a CSV file:
`"Barack Obama", 48, "President", "1600 Penn Ave, Washington DC"`

`string[] tokens = line.split(',')`

I expect this:

```
 "Barack Obama"
 48
 "President"
 "1600 Penn Ave, Washington DC"
```

but the last token is 
    `'Washington DC'` not 
    `"1600 Penn Ave, Washington DC"`.

Is there an easy way to get the split function to ignore the comma within quotes?

I have no control over the CSV file and it doesn;t get sent to me. Customer A will be using the app to read files provided by an external individual.

Comment: One option might be to use a different separator, like tab

Comment: The leader of the free world can't get his name spelled correctly?

Comment: Im not suggesting that he have to USE it. But its a free approach. Many people dont have license or dont want to use a paid software.

Comment: Benchmarks included in my answer.  If anyone else wants me to benchmark a different solution, I'm happy to...

Comment: @Damovisa - Please see my comments for your post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might have to write your own split function.

- Iterate through each char in the string
- When you hit a `"` character, toggle a boolean
- When you hit a comma, if the bool is true, ignore it, else, you have your token

Here's an example:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string[] SplitQuoted(this string input, char separator, char quotechar)
    {
        List<string> tokens = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool escaped = false;
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (c.Equals(separator) && !escaped)
            {
                // we have a token
                tokens.Add(sb.ToString().Trim());
                sb.Clear();
            }
            else if (c.Equals(separator) && escaped)
            {
                // ignore but add to string
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            else if (c.Equals(quotechar))
            {
                escaped = !escaped;
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        tokens.Add(sb.ToString().Trim());

        return tokens.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
string[] tokens = line.SplitQuoted(',','\"');
```

---

## Benchmarks

Results of benchmarking my code and Dan Tao's code are below.  I'm happy to benchmark any other solutions if people want them?

**Code:**

```
string input = "\"Barak Obama\", 48, \"President\", \"1600 Penn Ave, Washington DC\""; // Console.ReadLine()
string[] tokens = null;

// run tests
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    tokens = input.SplitWithQualifier(',', '\"', false);
Console.WriteLine("1,000,000 x SplitWithQualifier = {0}ms", DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds);

start = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i<1000000;i++)
    tokens = input.SplitQuoted(',', '\"');
Console.WriteLine("1,000,000 x SplitQuoted =        {0}ms", DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds);
```

**Output:**

```
1,000,000 x SplitWithQualifier = 8156.25ms
1,000,000 x SplitQuoted =        2406.25ms
```

Comment: Right, because no one else has ever run into this problem before. :)

Comment: Imagine that you have a CSV file with at least 5,000 lines. You will iterate through char, replacing it? A simple function will become an operation!

Comment: Well yes, a google search will give him obvious answers. And @Erup, of course you have to iterate through every character... how do you parse an entire string otherwise?!

Comment: You dont have to do it. Look at Amry answer (if you dont like mine).

Comment: Updated with code, but yes, I acknowledge there are probably easier (and more correct depending on your purpose) ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I like this.

Comment: @Damovisa: I'm not discounting your effort. In fact, you show a tenacity I haven't seen in quite a while. In the next day or two, I'll go back and use your solution and do the timing myself. For now I'm going with Dan Tao simply because he was the first with an elegant working solution. But I can be swayed.

Comment: I was curious how the benchmark would be affected by compiling the regex.  

Before:
1,000,000 x SplitWithQualifier = 6333ms
1,000,000 x SplitQuoted =        2022ms

After:
1,000,000 x SplitWithQualifier = 2333ms
1,000,000 x SplitQuoted =        1987ms

I'm probably getting way off the end of usefulness here, but for fun I added a cache to the SplitWithQualifier method so that after building a Regex (with the Compiled RegexOption) it was cached in a dictionary keyed by the delimiter and qualifier used to create it.  This cuts down alot of the cost of using Regex's.

Comment: I changed my vote to Damovisa. His solution is faster (and for me at least, more readable).

Comment: @Jeremy Wiebe - I might have to do another test using your suggestion. I only have 100 records so this is just nitpicking.

Comment: @ritu - Agreed, 1,000,000 iterations in seconds is pretty good.  If you're interested.  http://www.pastie.org/954823

Comment: I'll stick with damovisa because his solution is faster as posted.

Comment: Thanks guys for following this up - yeah, it looks like compiling the Regex helps a lot and brings the comparison closer.

Comment: If you remove `sb.Append(c)` from inside the `else if (c.Equals(quotechar))` block then your output will be stripped of the text qualifiers as well.  Great string extension, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 14):

I have a `SplitWithQualifier` extension method that I use here and there, which utilizes `Regex`.

I make no claim as to the robustness of this code, but it has worked all right for me for a while.

```
// mangled code horribly to fit without scrolling
public static class CsvSplitter
{
    public static string[] SplitWithQualifier(this string text,
                                              char delimiter,
                                              char qualifier,
                                              bool stripQualifierFromResult)
    {
        string pattern = string.Format(
            @"{0}(?=(?:[^{1}]*{1}[^{1}]*{1})*(?![^{1}]*{1}))",
            Regex.Escape(delimiter.ToString()),
            Regex.Escape(qualifier.ToString())
        );

        string[] split = Regex.Split(text, pattern);

        if (stripQualifierFromResult)
            return split.Select(s => s.Trim().Trim(qualifier)).ToArray();
        else
            return split;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string csv = "\"Barak Obama\", 48, \"President\", \"1600 Penn Ave, Washington DC\"";
string[] values = csv.SplitWithQualifier(',', '\"', true);

foreach (string value in values)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Output:

```
Barak Obama
48
President
1600 Penn Ave, Washington DC
```

Comment: I like it - probably better than mine!

Comment: This is awesome man! Given that so many people have so many options for attacking this problem - and this is one of the best, do you mind expounding on how your regex works? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5):

I see from the bigger picture that you are actually trying to parse CSV input. So instead of advising on how to split the string properly, I would instead recommend you to use a CSV parser to do this kind of thing.

### A Fast CSV Reader

One that I would recommend is the library (source code available) that you can get from this CodeProject page: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

I personally use it myself and like it. It's a .NET native code and a lot faster than using OLEDB (which also can do the CSV parsing for you, but believe me, it's slow).

Comment: I'll look into this. Thanks. I like the idea of a cvsReader so definitely this is something I'll add to my toolbox.

Comment: I use this library as well.  It's pretty good, although I've had some minor issues with extreme edge cases.

Comment: @Emil Lerch - can you give some examples? I'm sure the problems can be fixed if you point them out.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` for that. It will handle all the CSV stuff correctly for you, see: [A similar question with example using the TextFieldParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740993/read-only-particular-fields-from-csv-file-in-vb-net/2741005#2741005)

PS: Do not fear using the Microsoft.VisualBasic dll in a C# project, it's all .NET  :-)

Answer (score 0):

That would be the expected behavior as quotes are just another string character in C#. Looks like what you are after is the quoted tokens or numeric tokens.

I think you might need to use Regex to split the strings unless some one else knows a better way.

Or you could just loop through the string one character at a time building up the string as you go and build the tokens that way.  It's old school but may be the most reliable way in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse a CSV line with a simple Split on commas, because some cell contents will contain commas that aren't meant to delineate data but are actually part of the cell contents themselves.

Here is a link to a simple regex-based C# method that will convert your CSV into a handly `DataTable`:

http://www.hotblue.com/article0000.aspx?a=0006

Working with DataTables is very easy - let me know if you need a code sample for that.

Comment: I'm going with Dan Tao for now. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a regular expression instead.  It will allow you to extract more complicated substrings in a much more versatile manner (precisely as you want).

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prasad_1/regexppsd12062005021717am/regexppsd.aspx

http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/csharp-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score -1):

Can't you change how the CSV is generated? Using OpenOffice, you can set the char separator (use ;) and how the string is delimited (using " or ').

It would be like this: 'President';'1600 Penn Ave, Washington DC'

Comment: Just perform it on the "Save As" operation!

Comment: No matter what delimeter you choose, you still have to worry about it being in the data somewhere. Besides, he might get the CSV files from some external source he has no control over.

Comment: Yes. But its a quick alternative if he can open and change it.

Comment: No, it's too late to change the format of the csv file (as in seven years two late)

Answer (score -2):

string temp = line.Replace( "\"", "" );

string[] tokens = temp.Split(',')

Comment: That will definitely not do what he wants - he wants to keep the quoted strings intact - this code will remove quotes and then split them anyway

Comment: I can't modify the original strings.