# String split parse issue with space in C#

Tags: c#

I've a string like this

```
cscript "E:\Data\System Test Performance\Some Tool\script.vbs" "AP_TEST" %%PARM1
```

I'm splitting above string like below

```
cmd.Split(' ')
```

Expected:

```
cscript 
"E:\Data\System Test Performance\Some Tool\script.vbs"
"AP_TEST"
%%PARM1
```

But Actual results

[image]

Comment: you will have to escape the ", \ in the string itself.

Comment: Why would you expect that? I suspect "expected" should mean "I would like"... How `Split` is expected to magically figure out which spaces to take into account and which not?

Comment: It's not string split problem but a string parse problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space in the string so your result is as expected. Try splitting on the quote instead:

```
var str = @"cscript ""E:\Data\System Test Performance\Some Tool\script.vbs"" ""AP_TEST"" %%PARM1";

str.Split('"').Select (s => s.Trim()).Where (s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own split function which supports text qualifiers

Check answer here [Split String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807536/split-string-in-c-sharp)

Or this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15361/Split-Function-that-Supports-Text-Qualifiers

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
string[] newinp = Regex.Split(inp, "(?=\")").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many spaces in your E:\Data\System Test Performance\Some Tool\script.vbs (file location) thats why you're getting the wrong array.

You may do two things

1) Make directory which doesn't contains spaces
2) Modify code

```
string[] final=new string[4];
final[0]=cmdLinesplit[0];
final[2]=cmdLinesplit[cmdLinesplit.Length-2];
final[3]=cmdLinesplit[cmdLinesplit.Length-1];
for(int i=1;i< cmdLinesplit.Length-2;i++)
{
    final[1] +=cmdLinesplit[i]+" ";
}
final[1].Trim();
```

Comment: I can't change Folder Name to FodlerName. Thanks

Comment: No, See above accepted answer..

Comment: well accepted answer won't give u required string. it would give you path of file without quoted string. and AP_Test too. I just verified both answer.